# Quick sort errors in Python language

Tags: python

I am new to python so just to get familiar with the syntax, I am making the programs I have already made in C++ and Java.

```
def swap(p , q):
    temp = array[p]
    array[p] = array[q]
    array[q] = temp
def partition(beg , end):
    l = beg
    x = array[beg]
    for j in range(l+1,end) :
        if(array[j] <= x):
            l += 1
            swap(l , j)
    swap(l, beg)
    return l
def quick(beg , end):
    if(beg <= end):
        mid = partition(beg , end)
        quick(beg , mid - 1)
        quick(mid + 1 , end)

array = []
n=int(input("\nEnter the number of terms: "))
print("\nEnter the terms")
for i in range(0,n):
    val = int(input())
    array.append(val)
print("\nBefore Sorting: ")
print(array)
quick(0 , n)
print("\nAfter Sorting: ")
print(array)
```

This is the code that I made in Python for quick sort. It worked in c++ with the same range but it shows the following errors

**

1. Traceback (most recent call last):

   - File "python", line 28, in
   - File "python", line 17, in quick
   - File "python", line 17, in quick
   - File "python", line 17, in quick
   - [Previous line repeated 990 more times]
   - File "python", line 16, in quick
   - File "python", line 8, in partition
   - RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What value of n are you using?

Comment: This is probably unhelpful in solving this problem, but style tip: you can swap two values in Python without using a temporary value by doing `array[a], array[b] = array[b], array[a]`

Comment: Well, one obvious bug is that your `partition` function *always returns* `(n - 1)`, since that is the value of `i` in `return i` refers to the **global** `i`, which is last set in the for loop, `for i in range(0,n):` , did you mean `return l`? But you **really really** shouldn't be relying on global state.

Comment: Python has a maximum number of times you can loop or call a function recursively. I believe the value changes from system to system but there is a way to modify it. Really it's best just to break a large chunk into smaller parts and then narrow the larger data into smaller and smaller data.

Comment: @PrestonHager It does, but the problem with this code is **that it will recurse infinitely** <edited to remove erroneous comment where I confused quick-sort and merge-sort>.

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga I am sorry. I wrote that by mistake. it's lower case L instead of global i. But I am still encountering the error

Comment: How about trying `if(beg < end)` in `def quick(beg , end)` instead of `<=`?

Comment: @PranshuSharma please provide a [mcve]

Comment: It worked after changing the `if(beg<=end)` to `if(beg<end)`

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. It worked

Answer (score 1):

You program has a number of errors related to boundary conditions. Here is the modified and working solution based on your code. Note that I have changed swap to use the python preferred approach.

```
def swap(p , q):
    array[p],array[q] = array[q],array[p]

def partition(beg , end):
    l = beg - 1
    x = array[end]
    for j in range(beg,end) :
        if(array[j] <= x):
            l += 1
            swap(l , j)
    swap(l+1, end)
    return l+1

def quick(beg , end):
    if(beg < end):
        mid = partition(beg , end)
        quick(beg , mid - 1)
        quick(mid + 1 , end)


array = []
n=int(input("\nEnter the number of terms: "))
print("\nEnter the terms")
for i in range(0,n):
    val = int(input())
    array.append(val)
print("\nBefore Sorting: ")
print(array)
quick(0 , n-1)
print("\nAfter Sorting: ")
print(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `partition` returns `i`. That seems to be your loop variable for taking in the original input. So when you call `partition` to get the `mid` in the `quick` function, you're getting the same value over and over again. In python, loop variables stick around after the loop is done running.